# How to send messages to MS Teams using Java SDK

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to send messages using MS graph to MS teams. The SDK used is based on Java

**environment details :**

Java version : openjdk 17

microsoft-graph : 5.60.0

azure-identity : 1.9.1

the docs followed are : (using client secret)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=java#usernamepassword-provider
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk

we have set the proper permission in the azure active directory app registration (API permission ) ( delegated and application both)

here is the Java code written

```
final String clientId = "3cb5543544444444a9eb";
final String tenantId = "5435435-235435435435"; // or "common" for multi-tenant apps

final String clientSecret = "rewewrewiewrerewrewrz";

final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret).build();

if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
    throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
}
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
    scopes, credential);

final GraphServiceClient<okhttp3.Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
    .authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.content = "Hello World";
chatMessage.body = body;

graphClient.teams("4w45234324324fgf4d22-b5e4-94d0").channels("19%0thredfafdafdsfdstajhhgjhg4524554354354cv2").messages()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(chatMessage);
```

however, getting below error :

```
20:30:48.715 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO
com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential -- Azure Identity =>
getToken() result for scopes [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]:
SUCCESS Jun 20, 2023 8:30:49 PM
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError SEVERE:
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Graph service exception Jun
20, 2023 8:30:49 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail:
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code:
Unauthorized Error message: Message POST is allowed in
application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to
https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams
for more details.

POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/470b384c-c484-4d22-b5e4-94085c55d1d0/channels/19%3aec755a15c5514be3b630c8613572f132%40thread.tacv2/messages
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.60.0 SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.60.0 [...]

401 : Unauthorized [...]
```

As per the error message , does it mean that, the teams and channel should be in migrated state and if not, then we cant send messages using Java SDK to channel .
another point is , it says , Unauthorized .  but using postman client , if I hit the Teams API , then it works using the same secret and credentials ..

not getting how to make it work using Java code

please suggest on what is missing

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) doc, you can use either 'delegated' permissions, in which case the message be sent "on behalf of" a specific user, or 'Application' permission to have it appear to come from 'an app'. However, the doc also says:

> Note: Application permissions are only supported for migration. In the future, Microsoft may require you or your customers to pay additional fees based on the amount of data imported.

So there are better ways to consider for doing this. The easiest alternative is a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet).